# MarshalAsAttribute array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, attributes, marshalling

Im trying to read an alarm structure from a Beckhoff - PLC into a c# class.
First i have to make the exact same structure in c# and it currently looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Alarm
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 81)]
        public string text;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string objectName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
        public string[] instancePath = new string[6];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 24)]
        public string timeStamp;
        public int priority;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool acknowledge;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool disabled;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool alarmIn;
    }
```

Whats causing me problems is the "instancePath" field.
When the field is a string i can use the "UnmanagedType.ByValTStr" attribute with SizeConst and when it's an array "UnmanagedType.ByValArray" but when i want to use a string[] i don't know what to do.

I've tried creating a new class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class InstancePathDefinition
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string instancePath;
    }
```

And used in my alarm class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Alarm
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 81)]
        public string text;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string objectName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
        public InstancePathDefinition[] instancePath = new InstancePathDefinition[6];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 24)]
        public string timeStamp;
        public int priority;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool acknowledge;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool disabled;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool alarmIn;
    }
```

But when I use Marshal.SizeOf on my Alarm-class it gives me a size or 147 bytes instead of 189 bytes as I would expect.

EDIT:
I think the reason for the difference in size is that only the array gets initiated and the class "InstancePathDefinition" doesn't.

I tried changing it from a class to a struct and now the sizes match.

I still find it strange though that I can't combine both UnmanagedType.ByValArray and UnmanagedType.ByValTStr as a sub type with different SizeConst.

Next I will need to create an array of the alarm class and that will get me into the same trouble again.

Comment: You might try a fixed size char array instead (aka char[66]) Then you can put some helper fuctions in your class to extract the 6 strings you are looking for since they are at fixed offsets in the array.

Comment: Is the text data coming is a unicode or ascii in the data. If its ascii then you are going to need to set the character set as well.

Comment: Thanks user957902, Ive verified that i get the correct strings from the PLC so no need to change the character sets.

Comment: Where is the C++ declaration for the struct?

Comment: @user957902 P/invoke defaults to ANSI text

Comment: @David Heffenman It was not clear in what context structure was begin used. I would probably still explicitly declare it ASCII just to make sure that definition was completed if viewed stand alone.

Comment: @user957902 The CharacterSet declaration only applies to P/invoke. There is no other context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it an array of structures instead of an array of class objects.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InstancePathDefinition {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
    public string path;
}
```

Marshal.SizeOf() returned 189 when I tried it.